# Get index in ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array and I want to iterate through it initialize views based on array value, and want to perform action based on array item index

When I iterate through objects

```swift
ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
  CustomView(item: item)
    .tapAction {
      self.doSomething(index) // Can't get index, so this won't work
    }
}
```

So, I've tried another approach

```swift
ForEach((0..<array.count)) { index in
  CustomView(item: array[index])
    .tapAction {
      self.doSomething(index)
    }
}
```

But the issue with second approach is, that when I change array, for example, if `doSomething` does following

```
self.array = [1,2,3]
```

views in `ForEach` do not change, even if values are changed. I believe, that happens because `array.count` haven't changed.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

This works for me:

## Using Range and Count

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array = [1, 1, 2]

    func doSomething(index: Int) {
        self.array = [1, 2, 3]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<array.count) { i in
          Text("\(self.array[i])")
            .onTapGesture { self.doSomething(index: i) }
        }
    }
}
```

## Using Array's Indices

The `indices` property is a range of numbers.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array = [1, 1, 2]

    func doSomething(index: Int) {
        self.array = [1, 2, 3]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(array.indices) { i in
          Text("\(self.array[i])")
            .onTapGesture { self.doSomething(index: i) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe, that `array.firstIndex(of: item)` won't work if there are same elements in array, for example if array is `[1,1,1]`, it will return `0` for all elements. Also, it is not very good performance to do this for each element of array.

my array is a `@State` variable.


`@State private var array: [Int] = [1, 1, 2]`

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. If the array is a `@State`, the second approach works fine for me.

Comment: Never use `0..<array.count`. Use `array.indices` instead. https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md

Comment: In my case, it does render it! Are you on beta 4? Simulator or Preview?

Comment: Please note that [the iOS 13 beta 5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_5_release_notes?language=objc) give the following warning about passing a range to `ForEach`: “However, you shouldn’t pass a range that changes at runtime. If you use a variable that changes at runtime to define the range, the list displays views according to the initial range and ignores any subsequent updates to the range.”

Comment: Thank you, Rob, that explains the array index out of bounds error generated by the above - my array's content changes over time. Problematic, as that essentially invalidates this solution for me.

Comment: @TheNeil I am seeing same problem where I want to render view based on index and want to understand why this is happening? also what solution you come up with? thank you in advance

Comment: I don’t really have a solution, else I would’ve put my own answer to this question. A proxy binding, like in the following, looks like a possible workaround, but it’s messy and far from ideal. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61687192/2272431

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/ Using Index is not ideal if array content position can change like adding or removing content. As index is being used for implicit identification of views. We should explicitly set id modifier and use consistent id for same view

Comment: This works but generates warning "Non-constant range: argument must be an integer literal" and can cause crash if array count changes during ForEach execution.

Answer (score 235):

Another approach is to use:

## enumerated()

```swift
ForEach(Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
  // ...
}
```

Source: https://alejandromp.com/blog/swiftui-enumerated/

Comment: I think you want `\.element` to ensure animations work properly.

Comment: ForEach(Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, element in
    ...
}

Comment: what does \.1 mean?

Comment: @Luca `Array(array.enumerated())` has actually `EnumeratedSequence<[ItemType]>` type and its element is a tuple of type `(offset: Int, element: ItemType)`. Writing `\.1` means you access the 1st (in human language - 2nd) element of tuple, namely - `element: ItemType`. This is the same as writing `\.element`, but shorter and IMO much less understandable

Comment: Using \.element has the added benefit of swiftUI being able to determine when the contents of the array has changed, even though the size may have not.  Use \.element!

Comment: Yes, use `\.element` as @ramzesenok mentioned and implement `Hashable` protocol if you are using a custom object array, and add the properties that could change/update inside your object inside `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {` and there add for example in my case status update like `status.hash(into: &hasher)`

Comment: If the element type already conforms to Identifiable, you might want to use  `id: \.element.id`. If you used `id: \.element`, then the element type would require Hashable conformance.

Answer (score 67):

I usually use `enumerated` to get a pair of `index` and `element` with the `element` as the `id`

```
ForEach(Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, element in
    Text("\(index)")
    Text(element.description)
}
```

For a more reusable component, you can visit this article https://onmyway133.com/posts/how-to-use-foreach-with-indices-in-swiftui/

Comment: Using 'element' doesn't work for me. If I give it an array of 10 (Identifiable, Hashable) items, it only reports the indices of the first two elements of the array. It only works properly if I use 'offset' instead of 'element'. But I haven't tested animation yet...

Answer (score 32):

I needed a more generic solution, that could work on all kind of data (that implements `RandomAccessCollection`), and also prevent undefined behavior by using ranges.
I ended up with the following:

```swift
public struct ForEachWithIndex<Data: RandomAccessCollection, ID: Hashable, Content: View>: View {
    public var data: Data
    public var content: (_ index: Data.Index, _ element: Data.Element) -> Content
    var id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>

    public init(_ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: @escaping (_ index: Data.Index, _ element: Data.Element) -> Content) {
        self.data = data
        self.id = id
        self.content = content
    }

    public var body: some View {
        ForEach(
            zip(self.data.indices, self.data).map { index, element in
                IndexInfo(
                    index: index,
                    id: self.id,
                    element: element
                )
            },
            id: \.elementID
        ) { indexInfo in
            self.content(indexInfo.index, indexInfo.element)
        }
    }
}

extension ForEachWithIndex where ID == Data.Element.ID, Content: View, Data.Element: Identifiable {
    public init(_ data: Data, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (_ index: Data.Index, _ element: Data.Element) -> Content) {
        self.init(data, id: \.id, content: content)
    }
}

extension ForEachWithIndex: DynamicViewContent where Content: View {
}

private struct IndexInfo<Index, Element, ID: Hashable>: Hashable {
    let index: Index
    let id: KeyPath<Element, ID>
    let element: Element

    var elementID: ID {
        self.element[keyPath: self.id]
    }

    static func == (_ lhs: IndexInfo, _ rhs: IndexInfo) -> Bool {
        lhs.elementID == rhs.elementID
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        self.elementID.hash(into: &hasher)
    }
}
```

This way, the original code in the question can just be replaced by:

```swift
ForEachWithIndex(array, id: \.self) { index, item in
  CustomView(item: item)
    .tapAction {
      self.doSomething(index) // Now works
    }
}
```

To get the index as well as the element.

> Note that the API is mirrored to that of SwiftUI - this means that the initializer with the `id` parameter's `content` closure is *not* a `@ViewBuilder`.
> The only change from that is the `id` parameter is visible and can be changed

Comment: This is great. One minor suggestion - if you make data public, then you can also conform to DynamicViewContent (for free) which enables modifiers like .onDelete() to work.

Comment: @ConfusedVorlon oh indeed! I've updated the answer to have `data` & `content` public, as is the case for the original `ForEach` (I left `id` as it is), and added the conformance to `DynamicViewContent`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Not sure if it is important -but ForEach limits the conformance slightly
extension ForEach : DynamicViewContent where Content : View {}

Comment: @ConfusedVorlon I'm not sure either, it's tough to say without knowing the inner workings here. I'll add it just in case; I don't think anyone would use this without a `View` as the `Content` haha

Comment: Just a minor thing: `data`, `content` and `id` can be declared as constants.

Answer (score 31):

For non zero based arrays avoid using enumerated, instead use zip:

```
ForEach(Array(zip(items.indices, items)), id: \.0) { index, item in
  // Add Code here
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use a zero-based array? What's the context?

Comment: For example, an `ArraySlice`'s indices will be the indices of its items in its parent array, so they may not start from 0.

Comment: By using the index (`\.0`) as the id, you're not providing a consistent identity for the item, which will lead to view inconsistencies if `items` changes.

Answer (score 22):

I created a dedicated `View` for this purpose:

```
struct EnumeratedForEach<ItemType, ContentView: View>: View {
    let data: [ItemType]
    let content: (Int, ItemType) -> ContentView

    init(_ data: [ItemType], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int, ItemType) -> ContentView) {
        self.data = data
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(zip(data.indices, data)), id: \.0) { idx, item in
            content(idx, item)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
EnumeratedForEach(items) { idx, item in
    ...
}
```

---

As mentioned in comments by [Robin Daugherty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1589422/robin-daugherty) it's not a good practice to identify elements by their index in the array – it's fine sometimes but not when you want to reorder or insert/remove elements. Therefore if you want to do it right – conform `ItemType` to `Identifiable` (it's up to you then to identify each element properly) and use the element itself in the `ForEach` as an `id`, like this (notice `id: \.1` instead of `id: \.0`):

```
ForEach(Array(zip(data.indices, data)), id: \.1) { idx, item in
    content(idx, item)
}
```

---

**Small note**: `\.0` and `\.1` correspond to element from the first array you pass to `zip` and element from the second array respectively. It's coming from the tuple from array of tuples, created when you write `Array(zip(..., ...))`.

In this example since we pass `data.indices` as the first array, `\.0` is index and `\.1` is the element itself, since the second array we pass is just array of elements – `data`

Comment: This answer also uses the array index as the item identifier, which is bad practice. `ItemType` should conform to `Identifiable` and `id` should be `\.1`, referring to the element, not the index. See the answer by @onmyway133

Comment: thanks, you're right. I've updated the post and added more explanation

Answer (score 15):

`ForEach` is SwiftUI isn’t the same as a for loop, it’s actually doing something called structural identity. The documentation of `ForEach` states:

```
/// It's important that the `id` of a data element doesn't change, unless
/// SwiftUI considers the data element to have been replaced with a new data
/// element that has a new identity.
```

This means we cannot use indices, enumerated or a new Array in the `ForEach`. The `ForEach` must be given the actual array of identifiable items. This is so SwiftUI can animate the rows around to match the data, obviously this can't work with indicies, e.g. if row at 0 is moved to 1 its index is still 0.

To solve your problem of getting the index, you simply have to look up the index like this:

```
ForEach(items) { item in
  CustomView(item: item)
    .tapAction {
      if let index = array.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) {
          self.doSomething(index) 
      }
    }
}
```

You can see Apple doing this in their [Scrumdinger sample app tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/passing-data-with-bindings).

```
guard let scrumIndex = scrums.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == scrum.id }) else {
    fatalError("Can't find scrum in array")
}
```

Comment: this will lead to sluggishness when your have lots of rows.

Comment: While this does work, I've found it increases your chances of running into the dreaded "compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time" error. onmyway133 has a great answer below on how to do this well

Comment: if you don’t use item IDs then you can’t modify the array

Answer (score 11):

You can use this method:

.enumerated()

**From the Swift documentation:**

> Returns a sequence of pairs (n, x), where n represents a consecutive
> integer starting at zero and x represents an element of the sequence.

```swift
var elements: [String] = ["element 1", "element 2", "element 3", "element 4"]

ForEach(Array(elements.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, element in
  Text("\(index) \(element)")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The advantage of the following approach is that the views in ForEach even change if state values ​​change:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array = [1, 2, 3]

    func doSomething(index: Int) {
        self.array[index] = Int.random(in: 1..<100)
    }

    var body: some View {    
        let arrayIndexed = array.enumerated().map({ $0 })

        return List(arrayIndexed, id: \.element) { index, item in

            Text("\(item)")
                .padding(20)
                .background(Color.green)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.doSomething(index: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ... this can also be used, for example, to remove the last divider
>   in a list:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some View {
        let arrayIndexed = [Int](1...5).enumerated().map({ $0 })

        return List(arrayIndexed, id: \.element) { index, number in

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("\(number)")

                if index < arrayIndexed.count - 1 {
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. List is lazy, unlike ForEach, and this approach retains this behavior. Print the index inside .onAppear on a cell to see the difference

Answer (score 6):

2021 solution if you use non zero based arrays avoid using enumerated:

```
ForEach(array.indices,id:\.self) { index in
    VStack {
        Text(array[index].name)
            .customFont(name: "STC", style: .headline)
            .foregroundColor(Color.themeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea because it replaces the `Identifiable` object with the index, which means that SwiftUI won't be able to detect correctly when things change vs move.

Comment: @RobinDaughert how to avoid that if I still want to use ForEach with indices, because I got problem you mentioned

Comment: Both @onmyway's answer (which is the accepted answer) and @malhal's answer can give you a better method. If you must, you can use the [id function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/id(_:)) to place a meaningful identity on the view, but that's not necessary if you use `ForEach` correctly, as Apple recommends.

Answer (score 5):

To get indexing from SwiftUI's ForEach loop, you could use closure's shorthand argument names:

```
@State private var cars = ["Aurus","Bentley","Cadillac","Genesis"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(Array(cars.enumerated()), id: \.offset) {

                Text("\($0.element) at \($0.offset) index")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
//   Aurus at 0 index
//   Bentley at 1 index
//   Cadillac at 2 index
//   Genesis at 3 index
```

**P. S.**

Initially, I posted an answer with a "common" expression that all Swift developers are used to, however, thanks to @loremipsum I changed it. As stated in WWDC 2021 [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) video (time 33:40), array indices are not stable from `\.self` identity (key path).

```
ForEach(0 ..< cars.count, id: \.self) {     // – NOT STABLE
    Text("\(cars[$0]) at \($0) index")
}
```

Comment: This is considered bad practice and unsafe by apple when using SwiftUI you can watch Demystifying SwiftUI from one of the WWDCs for more info.

Comment: Using count and the index. All the index versions of this answer are considered unsafe. The  one with enumerated is the most acceptable version.

Comment: Using `enumerated()` doesn't change anything if you still use `\.offset` as the id. You need to use `\.element`.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty \.element doesn't work properly either. It doesn't provide access to all the indices in the given array.

Comment: @Womble The `Foreach` `id` argument should refer to the identity of the items being enumerated, not their offset in the array. Using `\.offset` as the `id` is not a stable identifier. @Andy Jazz both of your code snippets have the same issue because they're essentially the same. In any "real" scenario the item being enumerated should conform to `Identifiable`. In this case the item is a string, so `\.element` would be a stable identifier, as long as the array will never contain duplicates. See the answer by @onmyway133

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution though quite inefficient to the ones above..

In your Tap Action, pass through your item

```
.tapAction {

   var index = self.getPosition(item)

}
```

Then create a function the finds the index of that item by comparing the id

```
func getPosition(item: Item) -> Int {

  for i in 0..<array.count {
        
        if (array[i].id == item.id){
            return i
        }
        
    }
    
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use extension ForEach to resolve this issue:

```swift
extension ForEach {
  
  public init<T: RandomAccessCollection>(
    data: T,
    content: @escaping (T.Index, T.Element) -> Content
  ) where T.Element: Identifiable, T.Element: Hashable, Content: View, Data == [(T.Index, T.Element)], ID == T.Element  {
    self.init(Array(zip(data.indices, data)), id: \.1) { index, element in
      content(index, element)
    }
  }
}
```

How to using:

```swift
ForEach(data: array) { index, element in
    Text("\(index)")
    Text(element.description)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like they mentioned you can use `array.indices` for this purpose
**BUT** remember that indexes that you've got are started from last element of array, To fix this issue you must use this: `array.indices.reversed()` also you should provide an id for the ForEach.
Here's an example:

```
ForEach(array.indices.reversed(), id:\.self) { index in }
```