# SwiftUI dynamic List with @Binding controls

Tags: swiftui, combine, swiftui-list

How do I build a dynamic list with @Binding-driven controls without having to reference the array manually? It seems obvious but using List or ForEach to iterate through the array give all sorts of strange errors.

```
struct OrderItem : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var label : String
    var value : Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = [OrderItem(label: "Shirts"),
                        OrderItem(label: "Pants"),
                        OrderItem(label: "Socks")]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    List {
                        Toggle(items[0].label, isOn: $items[0].value)
                        Toggle(items[1].label, isOn: $items[1].value)
                        Toggle(items[2].label, isOn: $items[2].value)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Clothing")
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
            ...
                Section {
                    List($items, id: \.id) { item in
                        Toggle(item.label, isOn: item.value)
                    }
                }
            ...
```

> Type '_' has no member 'id'

Nor does:

```
            ...
                Section {
                    List($items) { item in
                        Toggle(item.label, isOn: item.value)
                    }
                }
            ...
```

> Generic parameter 'SelectionValue' could not be inferred

Comment: Solving this would answer the bigger objective: To create a ToggleList View that can take $items and manage, display the toggles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like

```
...
   Section {
       List(items.indices) { index in
           Toggle(self.items[index].label, isOn: self.$items[index].value)
       }
   }
...
```

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I missed that. I was hoping I'd be able to pass an actual object but that gets me where I needed to go. Thanks!

Comment: I can't believe it!! It does work. Why would this work and passing the object doesn't??!!

Comment: This approach seems to break when the amount of items in the array gets reduced later. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631225/using-foreach-loop-with-binding-causes-index-out-of-range-when-array-shrinks-sw

Answer (score 9):

While Maki's answer works (in some cases). It is not optimal and it's [discouraged by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021-10018/?time=455). Instead, they proposed [the following solution](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021-10018/?time=488) during WWDC 2021:

> Simply pass a binding to your collection into the list, using the
> normal dollar sign operator, and SwiftUI will pass back a binding to
> each individual element within the closure.

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = [OrderItem(label: "Shirts"),
                        OrderItem(label: "Pants"),
                        OrderItem(label: "Socks")]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    List($items) { $item in
                        Toggle(item.label, isOn: $item.value)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Clothing")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this limited to new APIs?

Comment: According to Matt Ricketson: "you can even back-deploy this code to any prior release supported by SwiftUI". In fact I think it uses a feature from [SE-0293](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0293-extend-property-wrappers-to-function-and-closure-parameters.md#closures) (which is implemented in Swift 5.5). But only installing the 5.5 toolchain in the old (v12) Xcode is not enough. I think you will also need to add the 
init(projectedValue:) to Binding and make it conform to the RandomAccessCollection in order to use this tweak with older versions of SwiftUI.

Comment: I confirm this is the way to set an individual binding to each row dynamically.  As a side note, l noticed that this doesn't work on Publisher wrappers. Only State wrappers.