# Reloading individual rows properties in SwiftUI List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

[image: I have a list here of news articles]

I am trying to give the user the opportunity to save or unsave a news article. The Save button saves it on the backend but the image does not update when the backend updates.

```
@State var industryInsights = [IndustryInsight]()

    List {
        ForEach(industryInsights, id: \.self) { insight in
            IndustryInsightRowView(insight: insight)
        }
    }
```

I am not sure the best way of doing this, but I would like the button image to update as the user presses the button. Any help would be appreciated.

InsightClass and properties

```
struct IndustryInsight: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let industry, alert, date: String
    let url: String
    let status: String
}
```

Function when save button pressed.

```
func saverowButtonClicked(alert: IndustryInsight) {
    if alert.status == "Saved" {
        RestAPI.changeStatusIndustryAlerts(id: alert.id, status: "Unsave", completionHandler: { () in
        })
    } else {
        RestAPI.changeStatusIndustryAlerts(id: alert.id, status: "Save", completionHandler: { () in
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: In SwiftUI you can't really reload an individual row, just let the system handle it. In the `changeStatusIndustryAlerts` closure, modify your `industryInsights` array and the List will automatically update.

Comment: @aheze thank you, could you show me what you mean.. the industryInsights Array is in another class though

Comment: You'll need to update your `industryInsights` `@State` variable.

Comment: @LukeTomlinson what class is your `saverowButtonClicked` func in? It's got to be related to your ContentView somehow

Comment: @aheze I have a RowView() with all those functions in it when a button is pressed. Then In my contentView() I have a List of RowView()

Comment: Might want to consider using a `Binding` for `IndustryInsightRowView`'s `insight` property, so any changes there will be passed back up to `ContentView`. Note that you'll need to [loop over `industryInsights`'s indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57837054/14351818) instead, unless you're developing for iOS 15?

Comment: @aheze I did this, and I am still having the same problem.

Comment: @aheze I need the property of Status to be reloaded when changeStatus is called

Comment: How did you implement the Hashable protocol for IndustryInsight struct? If done in the right way it should fire the reload of a row when changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to avoid using @State as much as possible and using @ObservableObject and @Published instead.
Try converting your IndustryInsight struct to an ObservableObject class and let IndustryInsightRowView accept it as an @ObservedObject.