# SwiftUI - Make a dynamic list of Pickers with unknown number of bindings

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a SwiftUI view that iterates over a @Published list in an @ObservedObject and creates a Picker for each item in the list.

I do not know how to make a dynamic list of @State variables to store the selections of all the pickers since the number of pickers is undetermined at compile time. Is there a way to create this?

How my code stub looks currently:

```
List {
            ForEach(vm.products, id: \.id) { product in
                ForEach(product.brands, id: \.id) { brand in
                    
                    let levels = vm.levels.filter { level in level.productId == product.id && level.brandId == brand.id }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
         
                        Picker(brand.name.uppercased(), selection: $selections[0]) {
                            ForEach(levels, id: \.id) { level in
                                Text(level.name)
                            }
                        }
```

Obviously $selections[0] doesn't work but I'm not sure how to create a @State object to hold those values.

Comment: In short the content for each item in the loop should be in their own sub view. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Make a simpler version of your view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI dynamic List with @Binding controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836990/swiftui-dynamic-list-with-binding-controls)