# Animating row change in a List with SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, ios-animations

Focusing on comprehending the underlying concept of the various animation behaviors, I am interested of programmatically animate the change of a row in a List.

I am able to achieve it in the following example:

```
struct First: View {
  @State var items = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item)
        }
        
        Button("Hit me") {
            withAnimation {
                items.swapAt(2, 0)
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

As you can see upon tapping on the button, we receive a nice swapping animation in the cells. We can see that cells are actually moving, one to the top and the other downwards:

[image: List: nice swapping animation in the cells]

When I change the list code to the following:

```
List(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
   Text(items[index])
}
```

As you can see the prior animation doesn't work anymore and instead I receive a text change animation:

[image: List: animation doesn't work anymore and instead I receive a text change animation]

Is there a solution to keep the first (default) swapping animation ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should watch "Demystify SwiftUI" `\.self` and `indices` are "unsafe" when dealing with SwiftUI. `ForEach` requires an identifier because SwiftUI depends on it for reloading, updating, animating, efficiency, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of identity. SwiftUI keeps track of view elements by their identity, and it can only animate between states when the identities of the single elements stay the same.

In the first code, the List id is of type `String`, the string changes place but keeps the same id.

In the second code the List id is of type Index, but when swapping the index does not change, only the relative string at that index.

So in result 1. animates the position based on string id, and 2. animates the string based on index id.

BUT you can tell SwiftUI explicitly which id to use, also in the second code, like this:

```
            List(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(items[index]).id(items[index]) // Here
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for the well written explanation, I was missing the 'why' behind the string animation.

Comment: Using array subscript in the `List` closure will crash if they remove the last item.

Comment: This is an unsafe solution watch Demystify SwiftUI

Comment: I focussed on understanding the concept behind the different animation behaviours

Answer (score 1):

You can't use indices with the `ForEach`, it's a `View` not a for loop. The first problem is the animations as you saw, the next problem is it will crash when you remove items.

When your list items are an array of value types in an `@State` you need to pass a valid `id` param, e.g.

```
List(items, id: \.uniqueIdentifier) { item in
```

The reason is so the `List` can track the inserts, removes and deletes. Value types don't have inherent identity like objects do because they are copied everywhere rather than a reference being copied.

Most SwiftUI Views that work on arrays like `List` make use of the `Identifiable` protocol to make this simpler, e.g.

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // this could also be a computed var that concatenates a bunch of properties that result in a unique string for this Item.

    let text: String
}

struct First: View {
  @State var items = [Item(text: "One"), Item(text: "Two"), Item(text: "Three"), Item(text: "Four")]

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List(items) { item in // no id param needed when the item conforms to Identifiable
            Text(item.text)
        }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks but you didn't answer the question

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. Take another look at the first sentence please, thanks.

Comment: wdyt about the accepted answer ?

Comment: That can crash if you remove an item from the array, many have had that problem, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335797/swiftui-foreach-using-array-index-crashes-when-rows-are-deleted

Comment: You mean if I'll use the offset/index from the indices ?

Comment: Yes if you do `items[index]` inside the `List` it'll crash

Comment: I totally agree with @malhal. You shouldn't be using the index version for the mentioned reasons. I focussed on explaining the concept behind the different animation behaviours, as I understood this to be the focus of the question.

Comment: Adding to the identity problem: if you use pure strings with `id: \.self`  and two strings have the same content, their id would be identical which leads to a number of issues.