# SwiftUI Array - Ignore nil Value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a JSON file which I have imported.
All records in the json file have an item which is an array consisting of between 1 and 3 items.
This is causing the list to fail as there are some records which have a single entry and other records can have 2 or 3.
When I specifically reference element 0, the app runs, but if I go to element 2 or 3, the app expectedly crashes. 
Is there a way I can get app to ignore nil values and run through.
Sample of JSON File

```
[  
    {
        "id": 1,
       "tla":"ABR",
       "name":"Abbey Road",
       "lines": ["Dockland Light"]
    },
    {
       "id": 2,
       "tla":"ACT",
       "name":"Acton Town",
       "lines": ["District", "Piccadilly"]
    },
    {
       "id": 3,
       "tla":"ALD",
       "name":"Aldgate",
       "lines": ["Hammersmith", "Metropolitan"]
    }
]
```

The goal is to list all lines regardless if lines consist of 1, 2 or 3

```
List {


                ForEach(self.allStations.dataStructure,id: \.id) { TubeLines in


                    Text("\(TubeLines.lines[0])")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)

                }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List {
    ForEach(self.allStations.dataStructure,id: \.id) { TubeLines in
        ForEach(TubeLines.lines, id: \.self) { line in
                    Text("\(line)")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }

        }
}
```

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ForEach loop with an index and count the elements of each array. Hard coding array indices is just asking for trouble. Something like this might work:

```
ForEach(0..<array.count) { i in
      Text("\(self.array[i])")
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
    }
```

I pulled this from this answer here [Get index in ForEach in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57244880/12772491)

Comment: The second answer was able to produce the result (lines) the first one error in that an identifiable was required. I put one in but got this error Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that '[String]' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'