# display index of each item in forEach loop in swift ui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wanna display the index of each item in ForEach loop inside SwiftUI views. I tried using an count and increment it everytime but the Xcode gives an error "cannot comform to views"

Comment: Hard to know what exactly you are asking about without code but maybe you are looking for [enumerated()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated)

Comment: Either iterate the `indices` of the array or `enumerate` the array

Comment: please share your code example to understand what you are doing and where's the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Swift Use .enumerated() with array to get index with item in for loop

```
let array = ["element1", "element2", "element3", "element4"]

for (index,item) in array.enumerated() {
  print(index,item)
}
```

for SwiftUI this link will help you

[Get index in ForEach in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244713/get-index-in-foreach-in-swiftui)

**Using Range and Count**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array = [1, 1, 2]

    func doSomething(index: Int) {
        self.array = [1, 2, 3]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<array.count) { i in
          Text("\(self.array[i])")
            .onTapGesture { self.doSomething(index: i) }
        }
    }
}
```