# Why Animation doesn't work inside a child view passed by Binding?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, observableobject

### Edit:

I found a solution but I would really like to know why it behaves this way as I got the solution by simply trial and error.

The solution I found is to add `.animation(.default, value: user.times)` modifier to the list in the child view. Why it works this way, I have no Idea.

I have this weird problem where when I pass a binding to a child view, changes inside this child view are not animated except for `.onDelete` modifier.

Here is a simplified code that produces this problem:

`Observable`(ViewModel) and model struct:

```swift
extension ContentView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var users = [User]()

        func createUser() {
            users.append(User(times: []))
        }
    }

    struct User: Equatable {
        let name = UUID().uuidString
        var times: [Date]
    }
}
```

`ContentView`: (Parent view)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(vm.users.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink {
                        UserView(user: $vm.users[index])
                    } label: {
                        Text(vm.users[index].name)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete { offsets in
                    vm.users.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
                }
                Button("Add") {
                    withAnimation {
                        vm.createUser()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Parent View")
        }
    }
}
```

`UserView` (Child View):

```swift
struct UserView: View {
    @Binding var user: ContentView.User

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(user.times.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(user.times[index].description)
            }
            .onDelete { offsets in
                user.times.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
            }
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    user.times.append(Date())
                }
            } label: {
               Text("Add Time")
            }

        }
        .navigationTitle("Child View")
    }
}
```

Notice in below image that the parent view having almost exactly the same code except for binding is working and animating as intended, and notice the child view `.onDelete` modifier is also animating as it intended but when adding to the list of child view, animation are not working.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: The problem is that the parent view's list is reloaded whenever the child view appends a new date into its`times` array. I don't think there's a way to animate adding items to the subview's list. Whenever a list item changes, SwiftUI reloads the entire list which in your case would cause both the parent and child view to reload.

Comment: Thanks @Anwuna! I actually found a way to fix but I don't really why it works that way. I'll update my question to see if people can get why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure the problem is in the use of `.indices`, since the `id: \.self` is now referencing the Int in the indices array `[Int]` not the User object in the `[User]` array,

If i recall correctly a solution is [to use enumerated()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244713/get-index-in-foreach-in-swiftui) in the following way:

```
ForEach(Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
  // ...
}
```